# Can I make a custom constructor for a custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have custom view extended from Constraint Layout.I only use it programmatically, without xml inflation.

Am I able to do like this without any hidden problems?

```
abstract class AbstractView(context: Context, var myParam: Any) : ConstraintLayout(context){

init {
    View.inflate(context, getLayout(), this)
}
```

Comment: But you'd require to inherit two other parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found you are able to do this without any drawbacks, but you just can't use them inside XML file.